Error when using TaskDialog in Excel VSTO application
I have Excel VSTO Workbook project and am using TaskDialog (from WindowsAPICodePack). On my home computer TaskDialog does work, but on my work computer I get the following error:

I know that I need to add app.manifest file with Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls uncommented:
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
        version="6.0.0.0"
        processorArchitecture="*"
        publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
        language="*"
      />
  </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>

But VSTO generates its own manifest, and I don't know where to add this element into VSTO's manifest. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

What is the OS on your work computer? Keep in mind that manifests are on the per process level, and your addin (being a dll) cannot supply it - it comes from the host process (excel.exe).

@DmitryStreblechenko Thanks for reply! Both computers are Windows 10.

Are you accessing that machine through remote desktop?

@DmitryStreblechenko Yes) How did you know that? ))

If theming is disabled (older OS, Remote Desktop, etc.), catch the exception and use the good old MessageBox or your own custom form.

My colleague tried to call TaskDialog, but it didn't show up.

Of course. But do you get an exception that you can trap?

There's no any exception!

You can check that the version of the already loaded instance of comctl32.dll is higher than 6.0 - use GetModuleHandle / GetModuleFileName / FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo
